# specify external system utility dependency in R package

Tags: r, package, dependency-management

I wrote a R package which uses `awk` to do some initial filtering on data. But the `awk` the package uses needs be higher than a certain version.

Where do you recommend to specify this dependency?

I can list the dependency in SystemRequirements in DESCRIPTION file
http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/how-to-list-external-dependencies-i-e-non-R-packages-td4693947.html

But it doesn't really do the check. Anyway, it may be good enough.

Comment: Accorging to this: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html the SystemRequirements field of the DESCRIPTION file is not checked. You may need to provide an installation script tailored to your (unstated) target OS. If there is a common response from a system call with option `-version` or `-V` from the unnamed external package, then you might be able to do some sort of check.

Comment: Thanks I'll check how to write  an 'installation script'. It is an internal R package only used on linux64.

Comment: I think that the later responses to the email thread you found had some Linux-specfic strategies.

Comment: Since this is a package meant only for internal use, the easiest way would be to leave it for your sysadmin to deal with. The second easiest way would be to write a custom install script/app that also checks for and installs the necessary dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

If you *really* wanted to go the long way, we now provide a template:

- package [x13binary](http://cloud.r-project.org/package=x13binary) installs the X-13ARIMA-SEATS binary from US Census
- it takes a binary from a matching GitHub repo [x13prebuilt](https://github.com/x13org/x13prebuilt) we have set up just to provide these binaries
- packages needing X-13 deseasonalization such as [seasonal](http://cloud.r-project.org/package=seasonal) simply depend on  [x13binary](http://cloud.r-project.org/package=x13binary)
- they then use wrapper scripts that find the binary as part of [x13binary](http://cloud.r-project.org/package=x13binary) and use it
- X-13ARIMA-SEATS is open source under a weird US Government license meaning that it is available as source, but with terms that vary a little a between the US and the rest of the world -- reflecting its origin from a world where license were less well understood.

This scheme might be overkill for you. On the other hand, you have simply no way to ensure that you will get the correct / minimally required `awk` version on Windows, OS X or arbitrary Linux.

Answer (score 1):

List it in the `SystemRequirements` field of the DESCRIPTION file.  For an example, see [Ryacas](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Ryacas/index.html).

Comment: Of course. And it puts all the effort back onto a human to do deal with it in a one-off fashion. Which. Does. Not. Scale. Hence our attempt to do one better, described in my answer.

Comment: Ryacas also provides a function to download yacas from a specific site controlled by the authors (Windows only) so if you use the provided facilities you can't really make a mistake in terms of versions.